# Handling exceptions from the synchronous part of async method

Tags: c#, .net, exception, task-parallel-library, async-await

I'm dealing with the situation where the task I start may throw, while still executing synchronously on the initial thread. Something like this, for illustrative purposes:

```
static async Task TestAsync()
{
    var random = new Random(Environment.TickCount).Next();
    if (random % 2 != 0)
        throw new ApplicationException("1st");

    await Task.Delay(2000);
    Console.WriteLine("after await Task.Delay");
    throw new ApplicationException("2nd");
}
```

From the calling code, I'd like to be able to catch any exceptions, possibly thrown from the synchronous part (i.e., until `await Task.Delay()`). Here's how I'm currently doing it:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        var task = TestAsync();
        if (task.IsFaulted)
            task.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        Console.WriteLine("TestAsync continues asynchronously...");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.ToString());
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to exit...");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

This works, although it looks a bit mouthful, as there is no `Result` on the `Task`.

I've also tried `task.Wait()` instead of `task.GetAwaiter().GetResult()`. That always gives me `AggregateException` which I have to unwrap (rather than expected `ApplicationException` directly).

Is there any other options?

**[EDITED]** To address the comments: I do this, because if the task fails instantly, I don't want to add it to the list of the pending tasks I maintain. The task itself knows nothing about such a list (and it doesn't have to). I still want to log the exception, and make user aware of it. I could also do `throw task.Exception`, but that wouldn't give the exception stack frame captured with `ExceptionDispatchInfo`.

**[UPDATE]** Inspired by other answers and comments: if I have full control over `TestAsync` and I don't want introducing new class members, I also could do something like below. It might come handy when validating arguments:

```
static Task TestAsync(int delay)
{
    if (delay < 0)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("delay");

    Func<Task> asyncPart = async () =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("await Task.Delay");
        await Task.Delay(delay);
        throw new ApplicationException("2nd");
    };

    return asyncPart();
}
```

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do this... I believe the compiler rewrites your `TestAsync` function into a class that's a state machine... if you decompile your EXE with something like ILSPY you can see. Taking an async method and running it synchronously is not the same as running a regular synchronous method unfortunately.

Comment: @JohnGibb, you mean no way of doing it, besides those two I mentioned?

Comment: I mean there's no way of having it throw the underlying exception instead of an aggregate exception. The task can be forced to run synchronously, but not with the same exception throwing behavior.

Comment: I'm sorry, I may have commented before entirely understanding your question. It seems weird that you only want to wait for the first chunk of the async method to run... it might help to describe more about what you're trying to accomplish overall.

Comment: Well, `task.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` re-throws the underlying exception on the synchronous execution workflow, so it actually gives me the desired behavior.

Comment: Maybe you're doing something like validating the parameters (which might throw an exception), and then beginning the async part? And you want `Main` to make sure that the validation succeeds, but then not wait around for the rest of the task?

Comment: @JohnGibb, yes it's a very similar scenario, besides I want those checks to take place inside the task itself. Basically, if the task failed instantly, I don't want to add it to the list of the pending tasks I maintain.

Comment: @Noseratio: I think your solution is the best you can do, unless you split up all your `TestAsync` methods into `Task TestAsync() { /* do stuff that can throw */ return TestInternalAsync(); } async Task TestInternalAsync() { /* async portion */ }`

Comment: @StephenCleary, thanks for your thoughts. Do you think using an async lambda instead of the split would make sense? I've updated the question with a sample of this.

Comment: @Noseratio: You could use a nested lambda like that. IMO it does reduce the readability of the code compared to separate methods, but it should work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd split it into two parts, rather than relying on `task.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` to work. I'd be afraid that someone maintaining `TestAsync` could unwittingly break things in the future.

This is how I would write it. This should preserve the behavior you've got, but I find it more obvious what's going on:

```
static Task Test()
{
    var random = new Random(Environment.TickCount).Next();
    if (random % 2 != 0)
        throw new ApplicationException("1st");

    return TestAsync();
}

static async Task TestAsync()
{
    await Task.Delay(2000);
    Console.WriteLine("after await Task.Delay");
    throw new ApplicationException("2nd");
}



static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        Test();
        Console.WriteLine("TestAsync continues asynchronously...");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.ToString());
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to exit...");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: This might be the way to go, acknowledged. However, in another scenario, the `TestAsync` might be implemented by the library I have no control over.

Comment: If it's another library, I'd rethink making such assumptions about the implementation of the async function. What if the synchronous part takes a long time in some cases? What if it's super quick, and then an error happens .001 sec later in the async part? Why not check for an error in the first second or something instead of caring about the "synchronous part"?

Comment: These are relevant questions. I do have the logic that observes the completion of background tasks already in the list. Nevertheless, I want to avoid adding a task to the list, if fails before it starts the async IO-bound operation (because, for example, the file is not found).

Comment: *What if the synchronous part takes a long time in some cases?* In such case, my calling thread will be blocked anyway (and so would be the the UI, if I called `TestAsync` from the UI thread). I'd have to resort to a workaround like `Task.Run(() => TestAsync)`, if I couldn't avoid using a badly designed library like that.

Comment: I'd accept your answer if you could change the `async void` signature of `TestAsync()` to `async Task`, and make `Test()` return it. Otherwise, there is no way of observing `ApplicationException("2nd")` outside `TestAsync` (other than with `TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException` or `AppDomain.UnhandledException`).

Comment: Made the change you requested - I had originally used `void` because the example ignored the return values anyway, but good call setting a good example.

Comment: The 2nd exception will never get caught because the results of the task aren't used anywhere - so even if `random` is 2, the 'Error' message is never printed to screen. You need to use `Test().Wait()` for the 2nd exception to be thrown (as an `AggregateException`)

Answer (score -1):

Generally speaking, exceptions should not be used for routine error handling in your application.  Throw exceptions for "exceptional" circumstances, where the program cannot continue because something unexpected happened and you need to do a hard stop.

Granted, I do not know precisely what your use case is, but whenever I'm using async tasks, the piece that is going to fail unexpectedly is usually also the piece that should be asynchronous (e.g. connecting to a database).

Regardless, how I would do this is to put your `TestAsync` method into its own class.  Then, you can have a method (or property) `bool TestAsync.IsValid` to determine whether the task is ready to go and should be queued for execution; then, you can run your async task if the answer is true: `TestAsync.RunAsync()`.

Comment: What about checking preconditions, like parameter values? That is a fairly common thing to happen early.

Comment: Chris, I don't believe in throwing exceptions to check preconditions. Those can be checked with if-statements. Unless it's an API, in which case you need to throw - but I doubt this is one of those cases.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You obviously use an `if` statement to check if the parameter value is valid. What do you do when it is invalid?

Comment: @rmayer06, any good library should validate its API arguments. Not that I know why your answer was down-voted, though.

Comment: @Noseratio, I agree with you. But this doesn't seem like an API as you would have no need to do synchronous validation inside a task if it were... I'm sorry I answered. Apparently good application design is lost on everyone.