# Contract agreement when implementing a method that returns a Task

Tags: c#, .net, exception, task-parallel-library, async-await

Is there a MS "best practice" or contract agreement when implementing a method that returns a Task in regards to throwing exceptions?  This came up when writing unit tests and I was trying to figure out if I should to test/handle this condition (I recognize that the answer could be "defensive coding", but I don't want that to be the answer).

i.e.

1. Method must always return a Task, which should contain the thrown Exception.
2. Method must always return a Task, except when the method supplies invalid arguments (i.e. ArgumentException).
3. Method must always return a Task, except when the developer goes rogue and does what he/she wants (jk).

```
Task Foo1Async(string id){
  if(id == null){
    throw new ArgumentNullException();
   }

  // do stuff
}

Task Foo2Async(string id){
  if(id == null){
    var source = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    source.SetException(new ArgumentNullException());
    return source.Task;
  }

  // do stuff
}

Task Bar(string id){
  // argument checking
  if(id == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("id")    

  try{
    return this.SomeService.GetAsync(id).ContinueWith(t => {
       // checking for Fault state here
       // pass exception through.
    })
  }catch(Exception ex){
    // handling more Fault state here.
    // defensive code.
    // return Task with Exception.
    var source = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    source.SetException(ex);
    return source.Task;
  }
}
```

Comment: Interesting question. I haven't ever seen such a guideline, so I'd be tempted to say 4: Method may either throw an exception or return a task containing that exception, and the caller should treat those cases as equivalent.

Comment: @hvd Defensive coding would suggest that the caller handle for both cases, but the minimalist in me doesn't want to handle exceptions being expressed in multiple ways.  The exception would be argument checking (sort of contradicting myself).

Comment: At the same time, though, the way an exception is thrown should not depend on whether the method was implemented using `async`, as that is an implementation detail not visible to the caller. If you agree with that, then either the two cases should be treated as equivalent, or you should never synchronously throw exceptions.

Answer (score 6):

I've asked a somewhat similar question recently:

[Handling exceptions from the synchronous part of async method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21055920/handling-exceptions-from-the-synchronous-part-of-async-method).

If the method has an `async` signature, it doesn't matter if you throw from the synchronous or asynchronous part of method. In both cases, the exception will be stored inside the `Task`. The only difference is that the resulting `Task` object will be instantly completed (faulted) in the former case.

If the method doesn't have `async` signature, the exception may be thrown on the caller's stack frame.

IMO, in either case the caller **should not make any assumption** about whether the exception has been thrown from the synchronous or asynchronous part, or whether the method has `async` signature, at all.

If you really need to know if the task has completed synchronously, you can always check its `Task.Completed`/`Faulted`/`Cancelled` status, or `Task.Exception` property, without awaiting:

```
try
{
    var task = Foo1Async(id);
    // check if completed synchronously with any error 
    // other than OperationCanceledException
    if (task.IsFaulted) 
    {
        // you have three options here:

        // 1) Inspect task.Exception

        // 2) re-throw with await, if the caller is an async method 
        await task;

        // 3) re-throw by checking task.Result 
        // or calling task.Wait(), the latter works for both Task<T> and Task 
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // handle exceptions from synchronous part of Foo1Async,
    // if it doesn't have `async` signature 
    Debug.Print(e.ToString())
    throw;
}
```

However, **normally you should just `await` the `result`**, without caring if the task has completed synchronously or asynchronously, and which part has possibly thrown. Any exception will be re-thrown on the caller context:

```
try
{
    var result = await Foo1Async(id); 
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // handle it
    Debug.Print(ex.ToString());
}
```

This works for unit testing too, as long as the `async` method returns a `Task` (the Unit Test engine doesn't support `async void` method, AFAIK, which makes sense: there is no `Task` to keep track of and `await`).

Back to your code, I'd put it this way:

```
Task Foo1Async(string id){
  if(id == null) {
    throw new ArgumentNullException();
   }

  // do stuff
}

Task Foo2Async(string id) {
  if(id == null){
    throw new ArgumentNullException();
   }

  // do stuff
}

Task Bar(string id) {
  // argument checking
  if(id == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("id")    
  return this.SomeService.GetAsync(id);
}
```

Let the caller of `Foo1Async`, `Foo2Async`, `Bar` deal with the exceptions, rather than capturing and propagating them manually.

Answer (score 5):

I know that Jon Skeet is a fan of doing precondition-style checks in a separate synchronous method so that they are thrown directly.

However, my own opinion is "it doesn't matter". Consider Eric Lippert's [exception taxonomy](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions.aspx). We all agree that exogenous exceptions should be placed on the returned `Task` (not thrown directly on the caller's stack frame). Vexing exceptions should be completely avoided. The only types of exceptions in question are boneheaded exceptions (e.g., argument exceptions).

My argument is that it doesn't matter how they're thrown because *you shouldn't write production code that catches them*. Your unit tests are the only code that should be catching `ArgumentException` and friends, and if you use `await` then it doesn't matter when they're thrown.

Comment: In the OP's case, would the exception possible thrown inside `Bar` by `this.SomeService.GetAsync()` be considered exogenous (I think so)? Should it be then wrapped with `TCS.SetException`, the way it's done there?

Comment: Yes, that's exogenous. I would implement `Bar` with `async`/`await`, which would use `TCS.SetException` under the covers.

Comment: I'd appreciate if you could show how `Bar` would look with *both* `TaskCompletionSource` and `async/await`. I feel like I'm missing something obvious. Thanks!

Comment: The `TCS` approach is what the op wrote in his question. The `async`/`await` approach would be `if(id == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("id"); await this.SomeService.GetAsync(id);` (ignoring the "just return the `GetAsync` task" optimization).

Comment: Ah, so it's *either* TCS or `async/await` like this http://pastebin.com/ncXH3T9X ?

Comment: @Noseratio: Yes, that's what I meant.

Answer (score 3):

The general case when methods return tasks is because they are asynchronous methods. In these cases it's common that an exception in the synchronous part of the method should be thrown just like in any other method, and in the asynchronous part should be stored inside the returned `Task` (automatically by calling an `async` method or anonymous delegate).

So, in the simple cases like invalid parameters simply throw an exception like in `Foo1Async`. In the more complex case regarding the asynchronous operation set an exception on the returned task like in `Foo2Async`

This answer assumes you're referring to `Task` returning methods that aren't marked with `async`. In those that are you have no control over the task being created, and any exception would automatically be stored in that task (so the question would be irrelevant).

Comment: +1. Agreed. Stuff like parameter validation has no reason to wait. If you can not throw immediately, then put it into the task.

Comment: I updated the example with Bar(string):Task.  Bar has a dependency on some service that returns a Task.  The example should exception/fault state is handled in 2 areas (try block and ContinueWith).

Comment: @Kevin yes. that's pretty much what i meant

Comment: @l3arnon: *In these cases it's common that an exception in the synchronous part of the method should be thrown just like in any other method, and in the asynchronous part should be stored inside the returned Task.* No matter if you throw from the synchronous or asynchronous part of `async` method. In both cases, the exception will be stored in the `Task`. The only difference is that the `Task` object will be instantly completed (faulted) in the former case. If `async` method throws from the synchronous part, but the caller doesn't `await` the returned task, the exception won't be rethrown.

Comment: @Noseratio the methods in the example are asynchronous, but not marked with `async` which is pretty common when you remove the redundant `async` modifier where it's unnecessary.

Comment: @Kevin and here's Jon Skeet's thoughts about it: "We're in a similar situation here, if we want arguments to be validated eagerly, causing an exception to be thrown directly to the caller" [How eagerly can we validate arguments?](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/11/01/control-flow-redux-exceptions-in-asynchronous-code.aspx)

Comment: @l3arnon, my point is that the caller should not make any assumption about whether the method has `async` signature. I don't think it's a good idea to use `TaskCompletionSource` for propagating exceptions the way @Kevin does inside `Bar`, I would simply do `return this.SomeService.GetAsync(id)`.

Comment: @Noseratio It's not about the caller, it's about the how to implement the method itself. about `Bar`, returning `SomeService.GetAsync(id)` is exactly what i said. The sync exception is thrown and the async exception is in the `Task`