# ConfigureAwait when not awaiting

Tags: c#, asp.net, async-await, synchronizationcontext, azure-webjobs

I have an `async` method I am using to offload a few seconds' worth of fire-and-forget work so as not to slow down my page load. This work needs a bit of general setup and tidy-up; I want the (fast) setup to throw synchronously if it throws, but I don't want to force the tidy-up to run in the ASP context so I am using `ConfigureAwait` on the bit I am awaiting:

```
public Task FireAndForget()
{
    DoSetup();
    return FireAndForgetAfterSetup();
}

private async Task FireAndForgetAfterSetup()
{
    await AFewSecondsWorthOfWork().ConfigureAwait(false);
    DoTidyUp();
}

protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FireAndForget();
}
```

This seems odd, because

- `FireAndForgetAfterSetup` shouldn't really care whether or not it is being called from an ASP context, so why should it have to be the one calling `ConfigureAwait`?
- If I change my mind and decide that `btn_Click` should wait for `FireAndForget` to complete, has it already thrown away the ASP context(?)

Can someone explain to me if I'm misunderstanding?

Comment: Currently your code *won't* throw synchronously at all. The task returned will be faulted, but the exception won't be thrown. I'd fix that first :)

Comment: Are you aware that "fire and forget" on ASP.NET actually means "I don't care whether this code actually gets executed"? Are you **absolutely sure** you don't care about that code?

Comment: @Jon Fair enough, I obviously understand less than I thought. Stephen Fire and forget might be the wrong phrasing, then, I just want to make sure the code is at least attempted.

Comment: @Jon It looks like I've messed up the implementation of [this pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21055920/handling-exceptions-from-the-synchronous-part-of-async-method) by not having separate `async` and non-`async` task-returning methods. I've edited the question in the hope of fixing that point while keeping the rest of it relevant.

Comment: Although I'm getting answers and comments about how IIS is just itching to take down an app pool and kill my work, I was really interested in whether it's a good idea to have a *library* `async` method defining behaviour which is related to the *UI* it's behind. I have taken on board Jon's comments about how I've implemented my synchronous part incorrectly, and everyone else's remarks about this being a bad idea, and TBH I've answered my *actual* question about `ConfigureAwait`  by reading some more of Stephen's blog articles.

Answer (score 3):

The ASP.NET synchronization context doesn't allow fire-and-forget work items to be kicked off from within a request.  The runtime actively monitors such things and will try to generate an exception since these code patterns lead to null refs, deadlocks, AVs, and other nastiness.

If you absolutely need to kick off fire-and-forget work in ASP.NET, consider using [WebBackgrounder](http://www.nuget.org/packages/WebBackgrounder).  It integrates with the ASP.NET extensibility points that are designed to allow for this.  So it won't block the active request, but keep in mind Stephen's caveat: it's not ever guaranteed to be executed *at all*.  If you require guaranteed execution, consider a reliability mechanism like Service Bus.

Comment: I find that odd, since I've definitely had this work to some extent. I fire off my event, and get the page result, but I don't observe the result of the "few seconds worth of work" until I make a later page load.

Comment: You basically just got lucky there.  This scenario definitely isn't supported.

Comment: Hi @Levi, can you please support this with any link or something? It is quite interesting.

Comment: @Levi ASP.NET does allow fire-and-forget tasks using the [Page.RegisterTaskAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.registerasynctask(v=vs.110).aspx) method, described in this [post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheMagicOfUsingAsynchronousMethodsInASPNET45PlusAnImportantGotcha.aspx) by Scott Hanselman. WebBackgrounder is a workaround with several limitations

Comment: I've just found [this article](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/12/returning-early-from-aspnet-requests.html), which implies that ASP just *doesn't care* if you've got tasks running all over the place, rather than actively monitoring them and blowing up if you try it.

Comment: ASP.NET most certainly does care.  See http://vimeo.com/68390507 (timestamp ~37:00), http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/web-development-best-practices/what-not-to-do-in-aspnet,-and-what-to-do-instead#fire, or my own video at http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/aspConf/aspConf/Async-in-ASP-NET for more information on async in ASP.NET.  Hanselman's article is about regular async work (*not* fire-and-forget), and Stephen Cleary's article has a huge disclaimer at the top which says "The solution in this blog post is not recommended."

Comment: @Levi so you *are* that Levi! Anyway the question seems to be about page async work (quote: `so as not to slow down my page load`), not really fire-and-forget work

Comment: @Levi thanks for that. I always use `IRegisteredObject` when I have to do something in parallel beyond the request lifespan, but I am glad to know now this.

Answer (score 1):

If your scenario is how to execute some (relatively) long-running task during load, ASP.NET allows this scenario through the [Page.RegisterAsyncTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.registerasynctask%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method. Scott Hansleman describes how to use it in [The Magic of using Asynchronous Methods in ASP.NET 4.5 plus an important gotcha](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheMagicOfUsingAsynchronousMethodsInASPNET45PlusAnImportantGotcha.aspx)

Essentially, you create an asynchronous method that returns Task and call:

```
RegisterAsyncTask(new PageAsyncTask(MyAsyncMethod));
```

then call [Page.ExecuteRegisteredAsyncTasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.executeregisteredasynctasks%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to start executing all registered tasks.

Scott Hanselman does a good job (of course) of describing why using an event handler, Task or background thread is a bad idea.

This is also described in "[What Not to do in ASP.NET, What to do instead](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/web-development-best-practices/what-not-to-do-in-aspnet,-and-what-to-do-instead#asyncevents)" in the "Asynchronous Page Events" section

Comment: I'd imagine this has the same caveats about how it'll die if IIS recycles the app pool. Does it allow the task to run longer than the ASP response takes to complete? Does it register the task with IIS so IIS will give it 30 seconds to complete?

Comment: @Rawling No, the method was created to avoid this situation. It actually notifies IIS of the asynchronous tasks (that's why it's called RegisterXXX). I'm still looking for the reference though

Comment: I can belive it's going to register the tasks with IIS so it knows to give them notice and time to complete (although I'd still appreciate a source for that, it's not exactly well-documented), but I'm not going to believe that IIS will give them all the time they want to complete :p

Comment: No, it won't. There is a configurable async timeout with a default of 45 seconds. You can also supply a callback to PageAsyncTask to handle timeouts

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why he didn't post it, but my exact two questions are answered in [this blog post by Stephen Cleary](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html):

> The important thing to note with this example is that each "level" of async method calls has its own context. DownloadFileButton_Click started in the UI context, and called DownloadFileAsync. DownloadFileAsync also started in the UI context, but then stepped out of its context by calling ConfigureAwait(false). The rest of DownloadFileAsync runs in the thread pool context. However, when DownloadFileAsync completes and DownloadFileButton_Click resumes, it does resume in the UI context.
>
> A good rule of thumb is to use ConfigureAwait(false) unless you know you do need the context.

- In answer to my first bullet point, yes, it's OK (encouraged!) to use `ConfigureAwait(false)` in library methods that know they won't use the context, because...
- ... in answer to my second bullet point, even if the library `async` method has thrown away the UI context, *the calling method still has its own copy*. Thus the calling method could `await` the library method and resume in the UI context... but it's going to deadlock when that happens.